# Questions for TriangulateMesh of F(X)yz library

Tags: javafx, javafx-8, javafx-3d

I 'm using the TriangulateMesh class to create a figure with its coordinates. There are some property to mark the lines that form the shape with greater thickness. When used DrawMode in LINE mode is possible to hide the hypotenuse. Thanks to all

Comment: I am on the F(X)yz team. Could you please describe in more detail the effect you would like to see? Do you have some code you could provide as an example?

Comment: Hi, I use the test Text3DTest of F(X)yz library. I would like to put a border to the letters. So the sides look better, It´s possible?